# Throwing an exception from XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, railo

I need XSLT to stop processing with an error, when an external document is not available. From what I've found out the <xsl:message> tag seems to be the right way to do it, but so far it doesn't work. Here's what I tried:

```
<xsl:if test="not(document('some_external_doc.xml')//myxpath)">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">ERROR: Missing element!</xsl:message>
    <h1>Error detected!</h1>
</xsl:if>
```

The missing document/xpath is detected by the <xsl:if> and the <h1> will be displayed, but for some reason the terminate attribute of the <xsl:message> is ignored. The transformation is done in Railo, so the XSLT processor use should be the Java default, but I wasn't able to find something definitive about the processor Railo is using.

Comment: Why not check schema before transformation?  There is a reason XSD was created.

Comment: You can use the `system-property` function in XML to get the properties `xsl:version`, `xsl:vendor`, `xsl:vendor-url`- this will tell you exactly what XSLT processor you're using.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea, however...

If your XSLT processor implements **XSLT 1.0**, it technically does not have to terminate.  Note the use of the word *should* rather than *must* in the [spec for `xsl:message`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#message):

> If the terminate attribute has the value yes, then the XSLT processor
>   should terminate processing after sending the message. The default
>   value is no.

Interestingly, **XSLT 2.0** [changes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-message) the *should* to a *must*:

> If the effective value of the terminate attribute is yes, then the
>   processor must terminate processing after sending the message.

Note also that order of execution of `xsl:message` statements is processor-dependent; keep this in mind when looking for `xsl:message` output in the logs.

Finally, you have some additional exception processing options under **XSLT 2.0** ([error()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-error) function) and **XSLT 3.0** ([xsl:try and xsl:catch](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#try-catch)).

Comment: To be honest, I think that wording change between 1.0 and 2.0 was more for clarification, rather than a change of meaning. I read that 1.0 definition as meaning it would be a violation of the spec if the processor does not terminate.