# How can I display exception messages from custom functoid errors in the BizTalk Administration Console?

Tags: error-handling, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

My goal is to influence the error descriptions that appear in BizTalk Administration Console in the Error Information tab of suspended instance windows, after errors occur in my custom functoids. If possible, I would also like the ErrorReport.Description promoted property to display this error description on the failed message.

I've read everything I can find about custom functoid development, but I can't find much about error handling within them. In particular, whenever my functoids throw exceptions, I see the boilerplate "Exception has been thrown at the target of an invocation" message that occurs whenever exceptions occur through reflection, rather than the message on the exception itself.

I had hoped to find something within the BaseFunctoid class framework that would allow me to submit an error string, so as to traverse the reflection boundary. Is there some way to pass error information from within a custom functoid, such that the BizTalk Administration Console will display it?

If I emulate the approach taken by DatabaseLookupFunctoid and DatabaseErrorExtractFunctoid, is there some way I can fail the map with the extracted error, rather than mapping it to a field on the destination schema as is shown in its examples?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is using custom C#, writing something like this in your code:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("EVENT_LOG_SOURCE", "Error message...", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
```

As Johns-305 mentions, you need to make sure your event source is registered (e.g. `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("EVENT_LOG_SOURCE", "Application")` - but this should really be done as part of your installation steps with an [`EventLogInstaller`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventloginstaller(v=vs.110).aspx) or some kind of script to set up the environment).  It's certainly true that error handling in BizTalk is just .NET error handling, but one thing to keep in mind is that maps are actually executing as XSLT, and the context in which their executing can have a major impact on how exceptions and errors will be handled, particularly unhandled exceptions.

**Orchestrations**

If you're executing a transform in an orchestration that has exception handling in it, the exception thrown will be handled and may even fall into additional logging you have in the orchestration - in other words, executing a `throw` from a C# functiod will work the way you'd think it would work elsewhere in C#.  However, I try to avoid this since you never know if a map will at some point be used else where and because exception handling in XSLT doesn't always work the way you'd think (see below).

**Send/Receive Ports**

Unfortunately, if you're executing a map on a send or receive port and `throw` an exception within it, you will almost definitely get very unhelpful error message in the event log and a suspended instance in the group hub.  There is no easy, straightforward way to simple "cancel" a transform - XSLT 1.0 doesn't have any specified way of doing that (see for example [Throwing an exception from XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644704/throwing-an-exception-from-xslt)).  That leaves you with outputting an error string to a particular node in the output (and/or to the `EventLog`), or writing lots of completely custom XSLT to try to validate input, **or designing your schemas properly and using a validating component where necessary**.  For example, if you have a node that must match a particular regex, or should never be empty, or should never repeat more than X times, make sure you set those restrictions on the schema and then make sure you pass it through the `XmlValidator` or similar before attempting to map.

Comment: I've got EventLog stuff going in External Assembly functions called with scripting functoids; however, I was hoping to facilitate easier administration by getting the error message right on the suspended instance itself. Instead, we have to do eyeball-correlation with timestamps to figure out which error goes with which instance, which is a pain. I also experimented with the error string output node approach, but this requires also mapping the entire source document into the destination as well so that it's available for more processing if an error is detected, which seems bad for our schemas.

Comment: If you need to do this for routing or message correlation, you could always check your values and have some output to a promoted property, and then route based on that...  but I think validation would still be better

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is, you just do.

Keep in mind, there is nothing special at all about error handling in BizTalk apps, it's just **regular** plain old **.Net error handling**.

So, what you do is catch the error in you code, write the details to the Windows Event Log (be sure to create a custom Event Source) and...that's it.  That is all I do.  I don't worry about what appear in BT Admin specifically.**strong text**